# Quickblox Chat Message Read Status

Tags: ios, quickblox

The [documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Message_model) suggests that you can check when the message has been "read", but there doesn't seem to be any such property in `QBChatMessage`. Am I missing something?

**Update:** It seems that "read" property is available in `QBChatHistoryMessage`, but what if I want to check whether a chat message I recently sent was read by the opponent? Can I do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBlox team has "added 'Message Read' status for Chat" in v2.0.10 — Oct 20, 2014.

[Reference: QuickBlox Framework Changelog](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog:)